# Is there any way to bind the function name from a JSON data to the (click) of a button in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, methods, binding

Hi I want to assign method name dynamically and use them.Please help.
I am trying something like following.

```
<div class="dashboard row">
<div class="card col-lg-3" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{card.title}}</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li *ngFor="let cardFeature of cardFeatures" style="padding-left: 7px;">
                <a href="" *ngIf="cardFeature.enable" [routerLink]="cardFeature.link">{{cardFeature.title}}</a>
                <button (click)="[cardFeature.method]">{{cardFeature.method}}</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CardFeatures is an array where I am defining the JSON data and there I am defining my method name so that I can dynamically read call that. But I am unable to achieve the goal.
Please help to resolve the same.
This is what I have in my ts file

```
cardFeatures = [
{
    "name": "id",
    "title": "ID",
    "enable": true,
    "link": "/register",
    "method": "meth1()"
},
{
    "name": "profile",
    "title": "profile",
    "enable": true,
    "link": "/link1",
    "method": "meth2()"
}
]

cards = [
{
  title: "Card1"
},
{
  title: "Card2"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtt6x5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
 cardFeatures = [
    {
      name: "id",
      title: "ID",
      enable: true,
      link: "/register",
      method: () => this.meth1()
    },
    {
      name: "profile",
      title: "profile",
      enable: true,
      link: "/link1",
      method: () => this.meth2()
    }
  ];
```

Template:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li *ngFor="let cardFeature of cardFeatures" style="padding-left: 7px;">
            <a href="" *ngIf="cardFeature.enable" [routerLink]="cardFeature.link">{{cardFeature.title}}</a>
            <button (click)="cardFeature.method()">Test</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

As per your comment, you can also try this [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kr1szd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. It is working fine. I am new to angular and trying something like above. Now I was trying the same solution but this time exporting and array from a ts file and getting undefined.myFunction() because of the this key word of angular.

Comment: Ok. Try like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kr1szd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much. You are saviour. The solution is exact same what I wanted to achieve since last few days. Bunch of Thanks